# Is scandir really thread safe?

Tags: c, io, thread-safety, readdir, scandir

In the [UNIX® System Threads Reference](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/threadsref.html), under the heading of "Thread-safety" is a list of functions are "not guaranteed to be thread-safe on all UNIX systems." The function scandir() is absent from this list, while readdir() appears on the list.

However the glibc [source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/dirent/scandirat.c) for scandir() clearly appears to call readdir(), not the thread-safe readdir_r().  So was scandir() omitted from the list for some other reason, or is it thread-safe for some reason I am missing?

Comment: A newer version of the "not required to be thread-safe" list is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01 but scandir still isn't listed. Would be interesting to compare BSD and SysV-derived sources if you have the time to track them down. A bug report should be made on glibc, probably.

Comment: It appears that glibc actually implements readdir() in a thread-safe manner, so probably no bug report needs to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) specifies that `scandir()` is thread-safe, since it is a [POSIX.1-2008 function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alphasort.html), and not in the list of functions allowed to be non-threadsafe.  However, POSIX.1-2008 does not preclude `readdir()` from being thread-safe, and in the case of glibc, it appears that the `readdir()` [source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/posix/readdir.c) actually is thread-safe, since it does not return a global `struct dirent`, rather it returns a [glibc-defined](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/make/3.82/w32/include/dirent.h) member of the `DIR` type returned in the `opendir()` call.

So even though glibc's `scandir()` calls `readdir()`, it still appears to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this list covers POSIX functions only.  `scandir(3)` is BSD/SVID and might not be listed there hence.  The new, thread-safe functions are probably the focus of this list but not listing old, thread-unsafe functions.